# Using library that calls requestAnimationFrame in Angular

Tags: angular, echarts, requestanimationframe

I'm using a library (https://echarts.apache.org/v4/en/api.html#echarts) inside Angular that internally calls `requestAnimationFrame`. When I have chart in idle state - I see stable 4-5% CPU usage and RAM keeps growing (leading to GC) and I see these `requestAnimationFrame` scheduled functions being called, which are hijacked by Angular.

I think I could reduce CPU usage if library could call native `requestAnimationFrame`, but is there any way to do it without changing the library? Even if I can do initial call inside `this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular` - `requestAnimationFrame` callback calls `requestAnimationFrame` and this time it's not inside `runOutsideAngular`, so we're back to Angular.

So the questions are 1) can I use native `requestAnimationFrame` there and 2) will I win some perf this way?

Comment: I think what you need to do is uncomment this line in polyfills.ts: `(window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame`. However, I think I have a related problem and that's not fixing it for me, so I'm not very confident in this solution.

Comment: @Nateowami looks like it turns it off globally. And I can't disable it just temporarily since this requestAnimationFrame runs in the background all the time. Won't it conflict with other components?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right it's completely global. If you need some components to requestAnimationFrame inside the Angular zone and some outside, then that's a perfect use case for dependency injection. But if the components don't support it that would make it complicated. It looks like echarts uses ZRender, which defines how it uses requestAnmiationFrame here: https://github.com/ecomfe/zrender/blob/e6d458c1e7bfeeb1949b3462d3a7d48d8dea12fc/src/animation/requestAnimationFrame.ts I don't see an obvious way to make it use a different method.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this exact issue. I'm working with ECharts 5, so perhaps it's different from 4, but I had the same expectations about `runOutsideAngular` not working with `requestAnimationFrame`, but [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts/issues/15#issuecomment-316633061) convinced me to try it, and it worked. I'm not using ngx-echarts, but it's the same issue, and the same solution.

I haven't gotten much time to actually dig in and figure out exactly what the minimum is, but I just went crazy and wrapped *every* call to ECharts with `NgZone.runOutsideAngular`: the initial `init` one, all event subscriptions, every and every call to `setOptions` and `resize`.

After doing that, the [Angular Dev Tools Profiler](https://angular.io/guide/devtools#debug-onpush) no longer showed hundreds of `requestAnimationFrame`-sourced change detections. So I'm quite convinced that fixed it.

As I say, I'm not sure if ECharts 5 is the key (or that I'm using the SVG renderer in ECharts), but I'd definitely give that a try if you haven't yet.

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely try it if we ever migrate to v5